# For some reason I cannot access a method of a class, derived from another class

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create custom Matrix class in Processing to work with any number of dimensions. Class RotationMatrix derives from it. But I can't access methods of RotationMatrix, as if they didn't exist.
My Matrix classes:

```
class Matrix{
  float[][] list;
  int[] dims;
  public Matrix(int cols, int rows){
    list = new float[cols][rows];
    dims = new int[] {cols, rows};
    
  }
  void Identity(){
    list = new float[dims[0]][dims[1]];
    for(int v=0;v<min(dims[0], dims[1]); v++){
      list[v][v] = 1;
    }
  }
  float[] mult(float[] vector){
    if(vector.length!=dims[0]) return vector;
    float[] result = new float[dims[0]];
    for (int i = 0; i<result.length;i++){
      float d = dot(vector, list[i]);
      result[i] = d;
    }
    return result;    
  }
  float dot(float[] v1, float[] v2){
    float result=0;
    for(int i = 0; i<v1.length;i++){
      result+=v1[i]*v2[i];
    }
    return result;
  }
  String toString(){
    String result="{";
    for(int y = 0; y<dims[1]; y++){
      if(y>0)result+=" ";
      result+="(";
      for(int x=0; x<dims[0];x++){
        result+=list[x][y];
        if(x+1<dims[0]) result+=",  ";
      }
      result+=")";
      if(y+1<dims[1]) result+=",\n\n"; 
    }
    result+="}";
    return result;
  }
}


class RotationMatrix extends Matrix {
  public float angle, scale;
  int ax1, ax2;
  int dim;
  public RotationMatrix(int dim){
    super(dim, dim);
    ax1=0;
    ax2=1;
    this.dim=dim;

  }
  
  public RotationMatrix(int dim, int a1, int a2){
    super(dim, dim);
    ax1=min(a1, a2);
    ax2=max(a1, a2);
    this.dim=dim;
    
  }

 
  void Update(){
    for(int y = 0; y<dim;y++){
      for(int x = 0; x<dim;x++){
        if(x==y) {
          
          if(x==ax1||y==ax2) {
            list[x][y] = cos(angle)*scale;
          }
          else {
            list[x][y]=1;
          }
        }
        else{
          if(x==ax2&&y==ax1){
            list[x][y]=-sin(angle)*scale;
          }
          if(x==ax1&&y==ax2) {
            list[x][y] = sin(angle)*scale;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now using Rotation Matrix:

```
m=new RotationMatrix(3);
m.Update();
```

And this call of Update method throws error "The function "Update()" does not exist". What am I doing wrong? I'm relatively new to Processing.
Edit: marking "Update" as public didn't help, restarting Processing either.

Comment: `m` should not declared as `Matrix` (i guess it is) but should be declared as `RotationMatrix`. A `Matrix` does not have an `Update`.

Comment: If the question is "solved" then you should accept the answer that solved it, **not** edit your question to include "solved".

Comment: @Mikhail Dolgopolov it's worth knowing Processing provides [`PMatrix2D`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix2D.html) and [`PMatrix3D`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PMatrix3D.html) for coordinate transformations, working in conjuction with [`PVector`](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PVector.html)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably declared `m` as `Matrix` instead of as `RotationMatrix`. But `Matrix` has no `Update` method, hence the error. You need to declare the type of `m` as `RotationMatrix` to fix this.

Next, since you didn’t declare `Update` as `public`, it’s currently package-private. If you attempt to access it outside the package in which `RotationMatrix` was declared, you will get the error you’re seeing. Declare the method as `public` to fix this.

(The same probably goes for most of the methods declared in `Matrix`.)

Comment: I've clearly written, how I'm declaring m:
      m=new RotationMatrix(3);
      m.Update();

Comment: @MikhailDolgopolov In Java, a declaration needs a *type* on the left-hand side of the variable name; what you’ve posted isn’t a declaration, it’s an assignment. Which Processing mode are you using that allows declaring variables without a type? Did you enter this in the REPL?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to change the type on the left, you're right. Question solved.